# Passing environment variable as python variable

Tags: python, environment-variables

Is it possible to transform environment variables to python variables ?

Example:

I have the following environment variable: `DATABASE=MYSQL`.

I want my python script to take this variable, then inside the script if i do something like `print(DATABASE)` it should give me `MYSQL`

I don't want to do this : `DATABASE = os.environ['DATABASE']`, because I don't know what the name of the variable will be in advance. I really want the script to treat environment variables as its own variables.

I feel like it is very bad idea to let code declare variables but still, I want to know if it is possible.

**EDIT**:

Why I want to do this ?

I have a `settings.py` that I can control with different variables. So I want to my `settings.py` to take environment variable as its own variables.

For example let's say today I want to set `PERF=MAX`, I want to just export this in the env variables and settings.py will take it as if it is it's own variable without me interfering.

And I don't want to hard code all the possible variables, because I don't want to maintain the `settings.py`

Comment: Instead of having it declared as a variable, why not use a dictionary, and have the key be `'DATABASE'` or whatever the name of the env variable is?

Comment: "don't want to do this : DATABASE = os.environ['DATABASE'], because I don't know what the name of the variable will be in advance. " If you don't know the name `DATABASE` then *how are you going to use the variable to begin with*?

Comment: `os.environ` already is a dict. All you need to do is `DATABASE = os.environ.get('DATABASE')`. There is no other sensible way because if you don't know what the name is beforehand because your initial `print(DATABASE)` would just fail with a `NameError` if the variables were injected at runtime and you didn't know what they were

Comment: @RandomDavis do you mean duplicate the `os.environ` dict? Why not just use `os.environ`?

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga. "how are you going to use the variable to begin with?"

Comment: You can name environment variables with names conflicting with Python keywords or builtins. This is a recipe for desaster. Whatever it is, find a different way to achieve it. BTW: Check out what a "XY problem" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What u r looking for is

Do not try this at home

```
locals().update(os.environ) # can use globals() as well(see comments below)
print(DATABASE) # if DATABASE is environment variable its value will be print
```

Comment: Never use `locals` for this. This *happens* to work in the global scope, because `locals() is globals()` will be true there. But it is explicitly warned that modfiying `locals()` is undefined behavior in the docs.

Comment: Yes this seems to do the job, thank you !.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I will check that out, thanks.

Comment: I agree it is unsafe, but the request to add env variables as local variable is odd.
why not just access the env variable directly?

Comment: @AvihayTsayeg I didn't say it was *unsafe* I said the proper way to do this is to use `globals()` instead of `locals()`, because the latter only *happens* to work while the former is *supposed* to work

Comment: I do not like messing locals() or globals().